# How do I properly push a layout upwards when using a Snackbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar

I'm trying to implement a proper snackbar that doesn't overlap other views, to do that I added to the activity a Coordinator Layout and inside I placed a constraint layout with the views I want to be pushed up. In the constraint layout I set the attribute `app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` but when the snackbar appears it pushes the views upwards but it is a little glitchy, here is the video:

[video](https://streamable.com/akbaa8)

The video is of an emulator but the same thing happens on real phones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".login.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/google_logo" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_outwire_logo">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerConstraintlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/create_account_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/facebook_sign_button">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dont_have_account_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/don_t_have_an_account"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/subTextSize" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/create_account_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/create_account"
                    android:textColor="@color/clickable_subtext_blue"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/subTextSize" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_user_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:autofillHints="Username, Email"
                android:ems="14"
                android:hint="@string/email_username"
                android:inputType="text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="TextFields" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autofillHints="Password"
                android:ems="14"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_user_email" />

            <com.app.custom.views.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/sign_button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sign_button_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sign_in_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password"
                app:text="@string/sign_in"
                app:text_color="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
                app:text_size="@dimen/sign_button_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
                android:textColor="@color/clickable_subtext_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subTextSize"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/or_sign_in_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/google_sign_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator_grey"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/sign_in_options_separator"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/or_sign_in_with_text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/or_sign_in_with_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/or_sign_in_with"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator_grey"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/sign_in_options_separator"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/or_sign_in_with_text"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <com.app.custom.views.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/google_sign_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/sign_button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sign_button_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorSecondary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
                app:src_logo="@drawable/google_logo"
                app:text="@string/google"
                app:text_color="?attr/colorOnSecondary" />


            <com.app.custom.views.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_sign_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/sign_button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sign_button_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/facebook_blue"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/google_sign_button"
                app:src_logo="@drawable/fb_logo"
                app:text="@string/facebook"
                app:text_size="@dimen/sign_button_text"/>

          

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have issues because you're trying to dodge insets with view that has height of match_parent so it gets resized and is forced to redo its layout. Personally I'd just abandon this behavior as it servers very little purpose and wrap your content with scroll view because right now you're committing the sin of hard-coding everything to fit a single display configuration.

Comment: @Pawel thank you I will follow your advice